# Zend Framework 2 zftool fatal error

Tags: php, terminal, zend-framework2

When running the zftool.phar I get a fatal error in the terminal.

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Form\FormAbstractServiceFactory' not found in phar:///Users/peter/Sites/zftool.phar/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 2

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to be an outdated version, downloading the latest version solved the problem.